# python docker how to mount the directory from host to container

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, dockerpy

can someone please share some examples of py apis showing how to mount the directories ? 
I tried like this but I dont see its working

```
dockerClient = docker.from_env()
dockerClient.containers.run('image', 'ls -ltr', volumes={os.getcwd(): {'bind': '/tmp/', 'mode': 'rw'}})
```

Answer (score 6):

#### By getting the container object

Change your code according to the following:

```py
import os
import docker

client = docker.from_env()

container = client.containers.run('ubuntu:latest', 'ls -ltr /tmp', volumes={os.getcwd(): {'bind': '/tmp/', 'mode': 'rw'}}, detach=True)
print(container.logs()) 

# => b'total 4\n-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 215 Feb 14 12:07 main.py\n'
```

Here, the container object is the key. To get it, you have to pass `detach` param as `True`.

Then it can print out the result of the executed command(s).

#### By setting streams

Another way to get the output is to set the `stream` parameter to `True` that returns a log generator instead of a string. Ignored if detach is true.

```py
lines = client.containers.run('ubuntu:latest', 'ls -la /', volumes={os.getcwd(): {'bind': '/tmp/', 'mode': 'rw'}}, stream=True)                                                                         

for line in lines:                                                                                  
    print(line)
```

docker-py is a wrapper around the docker engine api. Hence everything is executed inside the container and the result of the execution is available via REST.

#### By using subprocess

You can use `subprocess` module if you want to execute something and get its output on the fly.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["docker run ..."])
```

Doc:

- docker-py: [`client.containers.run(...)`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html)
- Engine API: [containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#31-containers)
- Subprocess: [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: is it possible to get real-time output of the logs when we run a command ?

Comment: I am trying to run a script inside docker and output of the script is printed using "dcoker run.." but doesnt print when I use python apis using print statement.
any idea ?