# Volume mapping in Docker using Python SDK version: 4.2.0

Tags: python, docker

I want to do volume mapping using my python code using docker SDK in python.
SDK version is 4.2.0 and command for doing the same in command line is

`docker run -v ./host_location:/container_location image_name`

I wand to do the same using Docker-py.

Comment: Did you try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43925629/5448990 ?

Comment: It is for version 1.10 
I wanted to do it using version 4.2.0

Comment: Then this should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54690144/5448990